# MediaObject in Actions on Google throws an error while using test simulator

Tags: actions-on-google, google-home, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I get a response something like this "Sorry, something went wrong. When you're ready, give it another try."

This happens when I change the surface to Speaker mode or Smart Display mode.
It does not appear while testing in the Phone mode.

Following is the response JSON I get:

```
{
  "payload": {
    "google": {
      "expectUserResponse": true,
      "richResponse": {
        "items": [
          {
            "simpleResponse": {
              "textToSpeech": "<speak><prosody pitch=\"-2.139st\">I am now loading Song#2 which is: <break time='500ms'/><emphasis level=\"strong\">Song_Name</emphasis></prosody></speak>"
            }
          },
          {
            "mediaResponse": {
              "mediaType": "AUDIO",
              "mediaObjects": [
                {
                  "contentUrl": "song_url",
                  "description": "song_desc",
                  "name": "song_name"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        ],
        "suggestions": [
          {
            "title": "Cast Vote"
          },
          {
            "title": "No"
          }
        ]
      },
      "userStorage": "{\"data\":{\"count\":2,\"countExit\":0}}"
    }
  }
}
```

And the Debug section displays the following in the visual response:

```
{
  "visualResponse": {
    "visualElementsList": [
      {
        "simulatorMediaResponse": {
          "mediaResponse": {
            "mediaType": 1,
            "mediaObjectsList": [
              {
                "name": "song_name",
                "description": "song_desc",
                "contentUrl": "song_url"
              }
            ],
            "startOffsetMs": 0
          },
          "mediaSessionId": "-1057369484946957721"
        }
      },
      {
        "displayText": {
          "content": "I am now loading Song#2 which is: song_name"
        }
      },
      {
        "displayText": {
          "content": "Sorry, something went wrong. When you're ready, give it another try."
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I want to know why is this happening only on Speaker and Smart Display on test simulator?

Answer (score 0):

Well, my solution cost me INR 3999. There wasn't an issue, it was just with the simulator. This issue doesn't persist on the device. The Action worked without any issues on the Google Home Mini.